Amazon Web Scraping: I can't scrape enough customer reviews
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import random

# HTTP headers
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.50',
    'Accept-Language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1'
}

# LUA script
lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
  splash:set_user_agent(args.user_agent)
  splash:go(args.url)
  splash:wait(args.wait)
  return splash:html()
end
"""

def get_soup(url):
    try:
        response = requests.post('http://localhost:8050/execute', json={
            'lua_source': lua_script,
            'url': url,
            'user_agent': headers['User-Agent'],
            'wait': random.uniform(3.0, 7.0)  # Randomize waiting time
        })
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        return soup
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching page: {e}")
        return None

# List for reviews
reviewlist = []

# Function to extract reviews
def get_reviews(soup):
    if soup is None:
        print("Soup object is empty, skipping this page.")
        return

    reviews = soup.find_all('div', {'data-hook': 'review'})
    if not reviews:
        print("No reviews found on this page.")
        return

    for item in reviews:
        try:
            # Convert rating string to float correctly
            rating_str = item.find('i', {'data-hook': 'review-star-rating'}).text.replace('5 yıldız üzerinden', '').replace(',', '.').strip()
            rating = float(rating_str)
            
            review = {
                'product': soup.title.text.replace('Amazon.com.tr: Customer Reviews: ', '').strip(),
                'date': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-date'}).text.strip(),
                'title': item.find('a', {'data-hook': 'review-title'}).text.strip(),
                'rating': rating,
                'body': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-body'}).text.strip(),
            }
            reviewlist.append(review)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error parsing review: {e}")

# Page loop
page_number = 1
while True:
    url = f'https://www.amazon.com.tr/HyperX-Cloud-III-Kulakl%C4%B1%C4%9F%C4%B1-USB/product-reviews/B0C3BSZ56D/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_prev_1?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={page_number}'
    soup = get_soup(url)
    print(f'Getting page: {page_number}')
    get_reviews(soup)
    print(len(reviewlist))

    # Check if there is a next page button
    next_page = soup.find('li', {'class': 'a-last'})
    if next_page and 'a-disabled' in next_page.get('class', []):
        break

    page_number += 1
    wait_time = random.uniform(5.0, 20.0)  # Randomize wait time
    print(f"Waiting {wait_time:.2f} seconds before fetching next page...")
    time.sleep(wait_time)

# Save results to a dataframe, then export as CSV
df = pd.DataFrame(reviewlist)
df.to_csv('hyperx-headset-reviews.csv', index=False, sep=';')
print('Successful.')

When I run this code, it only scrolls through 10 pages and I can't get over it.
I marked it in red, as it appears, Amazon says that I need to filter the comments after the 10th page and the next button is deactivated. I need to scrape more customer reviews for my project. What can I do to overcome this situation?


Perhaps the simplest approach is to simply do what Amazon suggests: use filters. You'd then loop over filter values and page numbers. More requests but also more data.
For example, you could filter by number of stars assigned.
DOMAIN = "www.amazon.co.uk"
PATH = "HyperX-Cloud-III-Wireless-microphone/product-reviews/B0CBQXGZ85/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_sr"

STARS = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

for page in range(1, 11):
    for stars in STARS:
        params = f"pageNumber={page}&filterByStar={stars}_star"

        URL = f"https://{DOMAIN}/{PATH}/?{params}"
        print(URL)

That should give you access to a lot more reviews.
If that doesn't give you enough resolution then you could use another filter in combination. For example, looping over page number, star rating and sort order (although you will have to deal with duplicates).
